# UML Domain Model of E-Commerce Site Feedback

Tags: uml, visio, class-diagram, domain-model

I have this assignment for school where I have to model a sort of e-commerce site that delivers grocery bags to customers (http://www.linasmatkasse.se/). I haven't received any use case, or anything.

The only directions I've been given is that it's supposed to be a domain model of max 40 classes, of a web based business (like described above).

[image]

This is what I have so far.

- Are the aggregations decent? (Especially between Customer and Account)
- Should OrderStatus & AccountStatus be associated or not?
- Is there any use for inheritance here?
- Are there any redundancies, or anything that should be added?

Appreciate any feedback! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for appreciating the feedback and improving the question. I think it is much more precise now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- change colors and font size of the picture, please - it is very hard to read.
- Aggregations aren't OK. Composition - black diamond means, that item belongs to container and can't exist without it. Of course, an item can't belong to two containers this way. Change to shared one or two compositions. Customer and account CAN be connected so. But better think of Account as of association between Customer and Website.
- Connect Cart and Order
- Why OrderStatus and AccountStatus should be connected? I don't understand, why they need to be connected directly?
- ItemDescription connect to item, or better, to ClassName, not itemlist
- Why OrderItemList is connected to WebSite? What is it at all? Why Order is not enough?
- What is SalesLineItem? Maybe, it should belond to OrderItemList?
- Change ClassName to ItemClass - don't use terms accepted for other things.
- Yes, you could use inheritance - Cart and Order should not be independent in this sense. But you'll decide, who is the parent. Or make "cart" one more status of Order. Or use both.
- Heaps of things could be added, but obviously, it is not the real task, merely a piece of play. Think way of delivery, way of payment. Show navigability. Show names of arrows, not of connections.
- Set attributes and functions.

Comment: Sorry, was expecting a larger image to be uploaded. When I wrote aggregation I mean't composition. Thanks a bunch for the response. Really helpful!

Comment: But you wrote absolutely correctly! Aggregations can be of 3 kinds - 'composition', 'shared'(non-strictly defined one), and 'none'. Very often people say "aggregation" instead of "shared aggregation" or "shared", but it is a BAD error to use parent name instead of a child one when opposing the subject with another child. So, I was glad that you are using the correct name - compositions ARE aggregations.

Comment: @Andorius I see there many errors. Please, put it as another question here, I'll react. Maybe not at once, but in 24h surely.